# How to pass list of file names to command

Tags: bash

`hindent --style johan-tibell --line-length 80 --indent-size 4 --sort-imports  -XQuasiQuotes` accepts filename as argument but how can I pass list of files as

I have variable `fileNames` that contains list of file names, I want to process each file using this command, can we do without any loop?

**Edit:**

The variable `fileNames` is declared using:

```
fileNames=$((git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E '*.hs'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can loop over using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) and a `for` loop:

```
for file in $( git diff --cached --name-only | grep -E '*.hs' ); do
  hindent --style johan-tibell --line-length 80 --indent-size 4 --sort-imports -XQuasiQuotes ${file}
done
```

Comment: You do not need a loop here at all: `hindent ... ${filenames}` works just as well, but it fails when a file has any spaces in its name.

Comment: @MaheshUligade See the updated answer. I provided some other options. You should also see cbley answer and see if using command substitution will work there.

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be if `fileNames` is an array:

```
hindent --style johan-tibell \
  --line-length 80 --indent-size 4 \
  --sort-imports -XQuasiQuotes "${fileNames[@]}"
```

Otherwise, you will run into problems when a file contains spaces, ie. any character in the `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) variable.

*Update*:

If this is just a one-off command, and you do not need the list of files any longer, you may simply use `xargs` in a one-liner:

```
git diff --cached --name-only \
  | grep -E '*.hs$' \
  | xargs -r hindent --style johan-tibell \
      --line-length 80 --indent-size 4 \
      --sort-imports -XQuasiQuotes
```

Comment: It only process the first file, rest of the file it doesn't process